# Create dynamic object from a JSON disregarding null fields

Tags: c#, .net, json, dynamic

I need to consume a method that the input parameter is a dynamic object, but I feed the object through a received JSON

Dynamic Builder:

```
 public static dynamic PayChargeObject()
    {
        var body = new
        {
            payment = new
            {
                banking_billet = new
                {
                    customer = new
                    {
                        name = "",
                        email = "",
                        cpf = "",
                        birth = "",
                        phone_number = "",
                        address = new
                        {
                            street = "",
                            number = "",
                            neighborhood = "",
                            zipcode = "",
                            city = "",
                            complement = "",
                            state = "",
                        },
                        juridical_person = new
                        {
                            corporate_name = "",
                            cnpj = "",
                        }
                    },
                    expire_at = "",
                    discount = new
                    {
                        type = "",
                        value = 0
                    },
                    conditional_discount = new
                    {
                        type = "",
                        value = 0,
                        until_date = ""
                    },
                    message = ""
                }
            }
        };
        return body;
    }
```

My JSON Data:

```
{
"payment": {
    "banking_billet": {
        "customer": {
            "name": "person name",
            "email": "personnamez@gerencianet.com.br",
            "cpf": "94271564656",
            "birth": "1977-01-15",
            "phone_number": "41991234567"
        },
        "expire_at": "2019-12-12"
    }
}
```

Note that json will not always have all available fields in the object filled, but the method I need to consume does not accept null values in the fields, and my problem is this, when deserializing JSON in the dynamic object, the fields not used in JSON are created as null in the dynamic object

JSON Convert and Method call:

```
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(MyJSON, PayChargeObject())
    dynamicMethod.PayCharge(obj);
```

[Dynamic Object with null fields on Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilrgp.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's not a dynamic object you are returning, it's an *anonymous type object*.  If you want to return a true dynamic object (one with no fixed schema that allows arbitrary properties to be added) you can deserialize to `ExpandoObject`.

Comment: Unlike true [dynamic objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject?view=netframework-4.8), anonymous type objects have a *fixed schema*.  Which means that the properties that are missing in the JSON must needs be present in the returned object -- with some default value.  And if you don't want `null` to be used, what values *do* you want for the missing properties?  The values in the incoming anonymous type object passed in?

Comment: @dbc You're right, I managed by replacing the block 

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(MyJSON, PayChargeObject())
dynamicMethod.PayCharge(obj);

with

dynamicMethod.PayCharge(JObject.Parse(MyJSON));

Comment: Well `JObject` has additional JSON-specific properties so you *might* want to use `ExpandoObject` instead.  But if `JObject` works then that's a win.  Shall I make it an answer?

Answer (score 0):

With help of @dbc solution:

replace:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(MyJSON, PayChargeObject()) 
dynamicMethod.PayCharge(obj);
```

with:

```
dynamicMethod.PayCharge(JObject.Parse(MyJSON));
```